# Python - I am getting an error but my output seems to be correct

Tags: python, tar

I have been trying to extract some images from three different directories inside of a .tgz file.

First, I found this code.  I tweaked the subfolder to get the correct one.

```py
import tarfile
import os 

def members(tf):
    l = len("img/champion/splash/")
    for member in tf.getmembers():
        if member.path.startswith("img/champion/splash/"):
            member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\splash', member.path[l:])
            yield member
with tarfile.open("Data\\tar\\dragontail.tgz") as tar:
    tar.extractall(members=members(tar))
```

This works fine but I need the files from the three directories and I tried to modify it like a class where I could just call on the different methods in that class.

```py
import tarfile
import os

class img_skins:
    def splash(tf):
        l = len("img/champion/splash/")
        for member in tf.getmembers():
         if member.path.startswith("img/champion/splash/"):
                member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\splash', member.path[l:])
                yield member
    with tarfile.open("Data\\tar\\dragontail.tgz") as tar:
        tar.extractall(members=splash(tar))
    
    def loading(tf):
        l = len("img/champion/loading/")
        for member in tf.getmembers():
         if member.path.startswith("img/champion/loading/"):
                member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\loading', member.path[l:])
                yield member
    with tarfile.open("Data\\tar\\dragontail.tgz") as tar:
        tar.extractall(members=loading(tar))

    def centered(tf):
        l = len("img/champion/centered/")
        for member in tf.getmembers():
         if member.path.startswith("img/champion/centered/"):
                member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\centered', member.path[l:])
                yield member
    with tarfile.open("Data\\tar\\dragontail.tgz") as tar:
        tar.extractall(members=centered(tar))
which I will just call like this:

img_skins.splash()
img_skins.loading()
img_skins.centered()
```

and everything seems to work fine.  It extracts the images I am trying to get but in the terminal I get this error:

```py
img_skins.splash()
TypeError: img_skins.splash() missing 1 required positional argument: 'tf'
```

However, if I remove the `tf` from the methods, then the methods don't work at all.  should I be worried?

Also, am I just over doing it?  Is there a simpler way to do things?  The problem is I have a folder, the img/champion one, and it contains four subdirectories but I only need three of them.

Comment: Note that, as the code is given, the `with` clauses are all incorrectly indented. This may just be from the cut and paste, however.

Comment: From what I could undestand, none of your your methods works, but the extraction accours because the identention of open file is wrong and when you instantiate the the class everything outside the methods runs immediatly.

Comment: As an aside, I should mention that if you are writing three different methods to do minor variations on the same task (in this case, operating on three different members within a tarfile), then you may want to reconsider how to combine them into one more general method.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA The original `with` statemet is correctly indented. It is intentionally global from what I can tell. In the class, there is defeinitely some weirdness  with the indentation.

Comment: The error is caused because you delcare `def splash(tf)` saying that `splash()` must take one argument. However, you call `img_skins.splash()` without any arguments. There is more wrong with your code than just this, so it is difficult to give an exact solution. You don't really need a class here. Instead, I suggest looking at what parts of your three new functions are different and see if you can find a way to modify the original function. You should be able to add one or more paramters to the original function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your original code, the `with` block is not part of the function. It makes no sense to repeat it inside of the `class`. Also, you need to declare an extra parameter named `self` in each function:

```
import tarfile
import os

class img_skins:
    def splash(self, tf):
        l = len("img/champion/splash/")
        for member in tf.getmembers():
         if member.path.startswith("img/champion/splash/"):
                member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\splash', member.path[l:])
                yield member
    
    def loading(self, tf):
        l = len("img/champion/loading/")
        for member in tf.getmembers():
         if member.path.startswith("img/champion/loading/"):
                member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\loading', member.path[l:])
                yield member

    def centered(self, tf):
        l = len("img/champion/centered/")
        for member in tf.getmembers():
         if member.path.startswith("img/champion/centered/"):
                member.path = os.path.join('Data\\tar\\new\\centered', member.path[l:])
                yield member
```

Now to use this class, you need to create an instance of it and call the methods on the instance. Note that in the original version, you call the function inside the `with` block. Instead of repeating the `with` multiple times, you only need to repeat the line that has the function call:

```
img = img_skins()
with tarfile.open("Data\\tar\\dragontail.tgz") as tar:
    tar.extractall(members=img.splash(tar))
    tar.extractall(members=img.loading(tar))
    tar.extractall(members=img.centered(tar))
```

That should fix the problem, but your code has a lot of duplication. Notice that the only differences in the 3 methods inside the class is two strings. This means you can just add some parameters instead of repeating the same function with these small changes:

```
import tarfile
import os 

def members(tf, parent_path, dest_path):
    l = len(parent_path)
    for member in tf.getmembers():
        if member.path.startswith(parent_path):
            member.path = os.path.join(dest_path, member.path[l:])
            yield member
with tarfile.open("Data\\tar\\dragontail.tgz") as tar:
    tar.extractall(members=members(tar, 'img/champion/splash/', 'Data\\tar\\new\\splash'))
    tar.extractall(members=members(tar, 'img/champion/loading/', 'Data\\tar\\new\\loading'))
    tar.extractall(members=members(tar, 'img/champion/centered/', 'Data\\tar\\new\\centered'))
```

Notice how this last version is much shorter than the class version. Adding variables and parameters helps us reuse code when only the data changes.

Comment: Unfortunately, this only solves part of the problem, as there is no `self` argument in any of these methods. While there is an argument `tf`, which the interpreter will interpret as the `self` argument, it seems clear that it is meant to be the tarfile argument.

Comment: @Schol-R-LEA Good point. I'm going to update my answer.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice thank you very much!!! this works like a charm, i am stille pretty new to python and really new to playing with tar files but your answer is actually so simple that it makes sense to me!

Comment: @Pendorax I'm glad this helps. I suggest you take some time learning more about functions. They are an incredibly useful tool to help reduce repetitive code. Don't worry so much about classes until you completely understand functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this code more simple by using "popen" in python instead. And If u are on Linux then that's a cherry on top.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).